# Unable to write mitmproxy flow results to sqlite3 database

Tags: python-3.x, mitmproxy

I am trying to store the mitmproxy flows to the database for further processing but when using the following code to insert into the sqlite3 database it's just skipping the insert into the database line and no data gets saved nor any errors are showing.

```
from mitmproxy.options import Options
from mitmproxy.proxy.config import ProxyConfig
from mitmproxy.proxy.server import ProxyServer
from mitmproxy.tools.dump import DumpMaster

import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('traffic.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS traffic (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,    
        path,
        method,
        status,
        request,
        response
        )""")
conn.commit()


class Addon(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 1

    def request(self, flow):
        print("flow.request.path")
        print(flow.request.path)
        c.execute("INSERT INTO traffic VALUES (null, :path, :method, :status, :request, :response)",
                  {'path': flow.request.path, 'method': flow.request.method, 'status': flow.response.status_code,
                   'request': flow.request.get_content(), 'response': flow.response.content})
        conn.commit()
        flow.request.headers["count"] = str(self.num)

    def response(self, flow):
        self.num = self.num + 1
        flow.response.headers["count"] = str(self.num)
        print(self.num)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = Options(listen_host='0.0.0.0', listen_port=8080, http2=True)
    m = DumpMaster(options, with_termlog=False, with_dumper=False)
    config = ProxyConfig(options)
    m.server = ProxyServer(config)
    m.addons.add(Addon())
    m.run()
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I used your code but a different approach, that I used for writing to text file before.
However, this seems to work, so thank you for the SQL part!

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('/home/pi/mitm/traffic.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS traffic (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,    
        path,
        method,
        status,
        request,
        response
        )""")
conn.commit()

def response(flow):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO traffic VALUES (null, :path, :method, :status, :request, :response)",
                  {'path': flow.request.path, 'method': flow.request.method, 'status': flow.response.status_code,
                   'request': flow.request.content, 'response': flow.response.content})
    conn.commit()
```

The I use mitmdump instead of mitmproxy this way:

```
mitmdump -s the_code_above.py
```

This works for me, hopefully it helps for your case, too.